# Link to the parent post in attachment page

Tags: php, attachments

I want to show a link on the attachment page which takes one back to it's parent post. Currently in my theme I do not have that option, the links I get on the attachment page are Previous/Next links. Please note I don't have any knowledge of php. I was wondering is there anyway if anyone can help me achieve this.

I would really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way within the main loop on the attachment's page:

First we get the parent ID from the current attachment's post:

```
$parent_id = get_post_field( 'post_parent' );
```

Then we check if it's non-zero and print the link to the parent:

```
if ( $parent_id ) {
    printf(
        '<a href="%1$s">%2$s</a>',
        esc_url( get_permalink( $parent_id ) ),
        esc_html__( 'Go to parent', 'wpse' )
    );
}
```

Hope you can expand this to your needs!

Comment: It works exactly like I wanted. Thanks a ton!  I really appreciate it!

Comment: Glad to hear it worked for you